# How can I remove a header border in an Ext JS grid panel?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I have a grid panel and I want to fully hide the header. I’m using the [`hideHeaders: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-hideHeaders) configuration option but it still leaves a faint 1px blue border where the header was. How can I not have that 1px blue header?

This is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehjf5x8u/) showing the problem.

[image: How it looks]
vs 
[image: How I want it to look]

I know it seems like a subtle difference but in my application that border looks really bad.  I thought this would fully remove the header but it didn't:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    hideHeaders: true
});
```

Comment: The CSS way - http://jsfiddle.net/ehjf5x8u/1/

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-css_var-S-grid-header-border-width

Comment: This seems very familiar with the issue I had with the "annoying red line".  Due to the height of the window, sometimes there would be an odd number of pixels and sometimes there was an even number of pixels.  This is sort of a hack for ExtJS 4.  It looks like theming (and CSS) improves a lot in ExtJS 6.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556891/what-component-event-should-css-classes-be-removed-in-sencha-extjs-framework-a/26557718#26557718

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this `sass` block to style my column headers:

```
.x-grid-header-ct{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecedee;
    padding-left: 15px;
    .x-column-header {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        .x-column-header-inner{
            padding: 10px 15px 15px 7px;
            &:before{
                border: none;
            }
            .x-column-header-text{
                color: #222;
                white-space: normal;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        }
        .x-column-header-over{
            background: none;
            .x-column-header-trigger{
                display: none;
                background-color: white;
            }
        }
        .x-column-header-inner-empty{
            background: none;
        }
    }
}
```